# I cannot find anything on setting up One signal in Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, expo

I am very new to react native development. I am using Expo for development. I need One signal for push notification in IOS and Android but I cannot find proper information on it. Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Expo doesn’t support OneSignal

From the first page of the OneSignal [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) for react-native

> If you are building an Expo project, please note that we have recently
>   updated the SDK so that it will no longer crash when you add OneSignal
>   as a dependency inside Expo's development environment. However, please
>   note that until you detach from Expo and link OneSignal's native SDK's
>   (along with React Native's own dependencies), any calls to OneSignal
>   functions will be unused.

If you want to use OneSignal you will have to [eject](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) your Expo app.

You can eject by running `expo eject` in the terminal.